# How to select a specific row from the table with one column as a sum of values of other rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Let's say I have a table called EmployeeInfo like following:

```
Name               Hours   StartTime           Date
John Smith           8          8:00                2013-12-11
John Smith           7          7:00                2013-12-10
John Smith           9          6:00                2013-12-09
Tom Smith            6          9:00                2013-12-11
Tom Smith            8          7:00                2013-12-10
Tom Smith            7          5:00                2013-12-05
Alex Smith           8          8:00                2013-12-10
```

I want query to return the following table:

```
Name               HoursToday   HoursWeekly    StartTime    Date
John Smith           8          24              8:00        2013-12-11
Tom Smith            6          14              9:00        2013-12-11
```

Where all info is taken from today's date except HoursWeekly, which is the sum of Hours from the given date (lets say 2013-12-9) till today. And the info should pop up only if employee has a record as of today (2013-12-11).
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?  typically this would be done with an inline subquery.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @Randy SELECT Name, Hours, (Select sum(Hours) from EmployeeInfo WHERE Date BETWEEN '2013-12-9' AND '2013-10-12'), StartTime, Date FROM EmployeeInfo WHERE Date = '2013-12-11'. But I don't know how to make sure that it calculates the sum of hours for current employee

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
  Name VARCHAR(50),
  Hours INT,
  StartTime TIME,
  Date1 DATE
)

INSERT  INTO @t
        SELECT  'John Smith', 8, '8:00', '2013-12-11' UNION ALL
        SELECT  'John Smith', 7, '7:00', '2013-12-10' UNION ALL
        SELECT  'John SMITH', 9, '6:00', '2013-12-09' UNION ALL
        SELECT  'Tom Smith', 6, '9:00', '2013-12-11' UNION ALL
        SELECT  'Tom SMITH', 8, '7:00', '2013-12-10' UNION ALL
        SELECT  'Tom SMITH', 7, '5:00', '2013-12-05' UNION ALL
        SELECT  'Alex SMITH', 8, '8:00', '2013-12-10'

DECLARE @input DATE= '2013-12-9';

WITH cte1 AS 
(
   SELECT name,
          hours HoursToday,
          StartTime,
          Date1
   FROM @t
   WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, date1, GETDATE()) = 0
),
CTE AS 
(
   SELECT name,
          SUM(hours) HoursWeekly
   FROM @t
   WHERE date1 BETWEEN @input AND GETDATE() 
   AND name IN (SELECT name FROM cte1)
   GROUP BY name
)

SELECT a.Name,
       a.HoursToday,
       b.HoursWeekly,
       a.StartTime,
       a.Date1
FROM cte1 A
INNER JOIN cte B ON a.Name = b.Name
```

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner solution than the accepted answer

```
SELECT e1.Name, e1.Hours HoursToday, e2.HoursWeekly, e1.StartTime, e2.Date
FROM EmployeeInfo e1
JOIN (
    SELECT Name, MAX(Date) Date, SUM(Hours) HoursWeekly
    FROM EmployeeInfo
    WHERE Date >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 7)
    GROUP BY Name
    HAVING MAX(Date) >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
) e2 ON e1.name = e2.Name AND e1.Date = e2.Date
```

Comment: It outputs every last start time, not only today's, and it counts all hours, not only this week's hours. Two where clauses could solve that

Comment: Added the `HAVING` clause in the sub query to only include if the date is newer than the current date

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
(select name, hours, StartTime, Date,
SUM(hours) over (partition by name) as totalHours
from mytable) m1
where Date = GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, haven't tested as don't have similar table but logic should work

```
select Name, 
Sum(case when date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111) then Hours else 0 end) as HoursToday,
Sum(case when date between dateadd(dd,-7,getdate()) and getdate() then Hours else 0 end) as HoursWeekly,
Min(case when date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111) then StartTime else '' end) as StartTime,
Date as Date

where date = '2013-12-11'
group by name,date
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work.

```
SELECT Name, Hours, 
(SELECT SUM(Hours) FROM EmployeeInfo WHERE Name = ei.Name 
    AND [Date] BETWEEN '12/4/2011' AND '12/11/2011') As HoursWeekly, 
 StartTime, [Date]
 FROM EmployeeInfo ei WHERE ei.[Date] = '12/11/2011'
```